# How is the expression "$cart.totals.total.value" formed in the prestashop cart process?

Tags: php, variables, prestashop, cart

I need to **disassemble** `$cart.totals.total.value` in the prestashop cart process, to show some information on a text *(like CMS Block)*, but I don't know how this is formed.

Can someone explain it to me?

What I need is to show in some `cart.tpl` a result like `(($qty * $price) - $ship)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can foreach the cart products, and display the qty*price block by:

```
  {foreach from=$cart.products item=product}
      {$product.quantity} * {$product.price} = {$product.price * $product.quantity}
  {/foreach}
```

And you can get the shipping price by:

```
{foreach from=$cart.subtotals item="subtotal"} 
    {if $subtotal.type eq 'shipping'}
        {$subtotal.value} 
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

**Update:**
Instead the `{$product.price}` use this,

```
{$product.price_amount|replace:'YOUR_CURRENCY':''}
```

In your case:

```
{$product.price_amount|replace:'R$':''}
```

Theoretically the price.amount should only show the amount in numbers, but it doesn't work for me on 1.7.8, probably this will be fixed in later versions.

Comment: Thanks, KoreLewi!
With your tip I could to get some precious values from $cart.
But my results are "0" (zero) with your foreach from=$cart.products. Like this:

9 * R$ 11,00 = 0
6 * R$ 11,00 = 0

Is this related with currency format?

Comment: @FlagKing Yes, the currency format makes the formula wrong. I have updated my original answer, please check it.
I tested it and it works fine for me: 2 * 24.28 = 48.56

Comment: Hi again;
Thanks! This little 'function' is very intersting.

Comment: Hi again;
Thanks! This helpful 'function' is very intersting.
I replaced 'R$' and the result is zero again. So I replaced the comma with dot. Same zero result. Finnaly, I replaced dot with nothing and same zero appears. I really don't understand why my presta [new instalation 1.7.8.0] don't recognize this numbers like really numbers. If I wrote somthing like {$total = 5 * 4} {$total} the result is 20. But if I wrote {$cart.totals.total.value} I get the R$177,25 for example. And {$cart.totals.total.value * 2} is zero. Just "0". Any *, /, + or -. Everytime is zero.

Comment: Hi. Try with the |floatval smarty function.  {$product.price_amount|replace:'R$':''|floatval} . This converts the R$177,25 to a float number 177.25

Comment: I tried to use $cart.totals in this case: {$cart.totals.total.value|replace:'R$':''|floatval} but the value returns zero everytime. I just cant understand this. Really. I'm using the module "pscartbanner". This module insert a banner with informations about the cart. The banner shows this values correctly but appears just strings not numbers. This is possible?